# CSS Moving an Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to develop a theme, and I want to choose where to place my image.  But only for that image.  I am doing it with css. When I do

```
img {
[DIMENSIONS AND STUFF
}
```

it moves all the images to the selected place.  I only want it to move one image.  Help.

Answer (score 3):

Specify an ID selector for it.

**HTML**

```
<img src="" id="image" />
```

**CSS**

```
#image {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
<img class="whatever" src="..." alt="..." />
```

and then in your stylesheet:

```
.whatever {
DIMENSIONS AND STUFF
}
```

Comment: Waht?!?!?!!??!!?!??!?!??

Comment: you have to give the each img tag a unique name or "class" to style it. And try reloading this page, cuz I edited my answer.

Comment: +1 for the alt property. Though I would have suggested an `id` for identifying a single unique image.

Answer (score 1):

Add `id="theName"` to the `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img id="theName" />
```

Then in css, you write:

```
#theName {
[DIMENSIONS AND STUFF]
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `img #theName` is a) never going to target the image itself because you are targeting a child of an image (impossible) and b) using other selectors (especially expensive ones like those based on tags - img etc.) in combination with id selectors is completely redundant?

Comment: I never knew the a) (In fact, I always used directly `#theName` but I saw `div #theName` sometimes and thought it was the same.

Comment: Id selectors usually have a high enough specificity to be used alone but they can be very useful for namespacing which is basically preventing descendant from being affected by other selectors. I.e. if you have an unordered list with an id selector `#mainMenu` you could easily protect its descendants (`<li>` elements) by specifying rules inside a `#mainMenu li` selector (very strong specificity and thus protection).